# How do I get MobaXTerm's theme in the VSCode bash terminal for Linux?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, terminal, mobaxterm

I want to start using VSCode for learning Linux, but I found the MobaXterm's interface friendlier because of all the colors making whatever is on display easier to find and read.

Since I will be using lots of "--help", colors really help.

All help is welcomed!

By the way, I tried those "themes" (...) to put inside settings.json in VSCode:

"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
(...)
}

This only changes background and a few more things, it doesn't highlight some Linux keywords like I want it to, like MobaXterm does (e.g. "ls --help", lots of different colors and highlights apper)

Comment: Why not install a Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL) to learn about Linux? Relevant installation link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install